# Integrating Executable Jar file in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, jar, cordova-plugins, executable-jar, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Ionic and had a executable jar file, how can i integrate it in Ionic.

I have learned how to make a custom cordova Plugin but it doesn't help me Much.

Any help will be highly Appreciated.